# Reducing the line spacing of multi-line section headings in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, line-spacing

[This is essentially a memoir-specific version of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43899/14996).]

**How can I reduce the line spacing within section (or other) headings in `memoir` without affecting the spacing to the body text above?**

In the example that follows, modifying `\baselineskip` does the trick but also affects the spacing of the heading to the previous section's body text. I would like to get rid of this unintended side effect.

Further notes about my example: Note that halving `\baselineskip` is too much, but it's good for illustrating the issue. I've included `\tableofcontents` and used the optional-argument version of `\section` (`\section[what appears in the TOC]{what appears in the document body}`) to draw attention to the fact that whatever modifications of the section heading we make, we probably don't want to affect the table of contents. For those taking issue with the visuals of the example ("The original line spacing is just fine in what you show below!"), the actual problem is from something else (my other, actual document has horrible double-spacing); **update:** I have included a screenshot for that as well.

Notes for those helping with a solution: 1. It seems that `\par` can't be issued within a section heading. 2. `\setstretch` (from the solutions to the linked question) doesn't work within `memoir`.

[image: too-large line spacing in section headings (ordinary spacing for main document)]

This issue is exacerbated by doublespacing (add `\DoubleSpacing` in the preamble):

[image: too-large line spacing in section headings (double spacing for main document)]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

%\DoubleSpacing


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{This is a chapter heading}

Look at the distance of this line to the following heading (as intended):

\section{This is a section heading spanning two lines}

Look at the distance of this line to the following heading (slightly too small):

\section[This is a section heading spanning two lines]%
    {\setlength{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
     This is a section heading spanning two lines}

Text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The way you can fix this manually is to re-introduce the correct `\baselineskip` in the form of a strut. That is, insert `\rule{0pt}{22pt}` at the start of the section title (22pt = `\baselineskip` within `\section`).

Comment: Just specify the font size and baseline skip in the configuration of the sections look (`\setsecheadstyle`), remember the two arguments of `\fontsize`

Comment: @daleif But how do I remember what the 2 effective arguments of `\fontsize` would be? Also my actual document has `\DoubleSpacing` in the preamble. Could you try writing an answer?

Comment: That is even worse, please update your example. The I'll have a look when I'm at a computer. Btw, if the doc is suppose to be double spaced, then why not the section titles?

Comment: @daleif I've updated my example, though - as originally described - there wasn't much to update.

Comment: @Werner [To others: His remark was for the case without `\DoubleSpacing`.] This works for me if the section heading is after body text on the page, but if the section heading ends up at the top of the page, it appears lower than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer (for a `\DoubleSpacing` context):

```
\preto{\secheadstyle}{\setSpacing{1}} % requires package "etoolbox"
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-14.41pt}
```

The adjustment for `\beforesecskip` is negative because `\beforesecskip` is already negative and, as user `egreg` points out, a negative skip is used in its positive/absolute value but is given in a negative number to indicate that the paragraph after the title will not be indented.

Naturally, the adjustment required for `\beforesecskip` in order to keep the spacing of the heading to any text before the heading constant depends on one's document spacing (here `\DoubleSpacing`) and on the reset of the spacing (here `1`, as fed to the `memoir`-internal `\setSpacing` macro). One can compute this value manually as follows: `memoir`'s `\DoubleSpacing` executes `\setSpacing{1.655}` for `12pt`, and we can calculate 22pt*(1.655-1)=14.41pt, where `\baselineskip`=`22pt` within the section heading for normal single spacing. The cause for the `22pt` is the invocation of `\secheadstyle` for the section heading. The official way to modify `\secheadstyle` is via `\setsecheadstyle`, but I'm keeping things as general as possible and simply prepend my change via `etoolbox`'s `\preto`.

I will demonstrate that this works, but by making manual adjustments, contrasting "no adjustment" with "adjustment", for non-page-initial as well as page-initial section headings. The following screenshot shows a contrast in a non-page-initial scenario, where the distance of the section heading to the immediately preceding text is identical for both (due to my adjustment to `\beforesecskip`):

[image: section heading with adjusted internal spacing]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}

\DoubleSpacing


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


% computing the required adjustment:
\newlength{\secbaselineskip}
\newlength{\secbaselineskipAdjusted}
\newlength{\secbaselineskipDiff}
  {
  \secheadstyle
    \setlength{\secbaselineskip}{\the\baselineskip}%
    \global\secbaselineskip=\secbaselineskip
    % evaluates to 36.40997pt
  \setSpacing{1}
    \global\setlength{\secbaselineskipAdjusted}{\the\baselineskip}%
    \global\secbaselineskipAdjusted=\secbaselineskipAdjusted
    % evaluates to 22.0pt
  }
\setlength{\secbaselineskipDiff}{\secbaselineskip-\secbaselineskipAdjusted}
% evaluates to 14.40997pt


\newpage


\noindent
Text.


% no adjustment, non-page-initial section heading
\section{This is a section heading spanning two lines}

Text.


% adjustment, non-page-initial section heading
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-\secbaselineskipDiff}
\section[This is a section heading spanning two lines]{\setSpacing{1}\relax
  This is a section heading spanning two lines}
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{\secbaselineskipDiff}

Text.


\newpage
% no adjustment, page-initial section heading
\section{This is a section heading spanning two lines}

Text.


\newpage
% adjustment, page-initial section heading
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-\secbaselineskipDiff}
\section[This is a section heading spanning two lines]{\setSpacing{1}\relax
  This is a section heading spanning two lines}
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{\secbaselineskipDiff}

Text.

\end{document}
```

In the computation of the difference in `\baselineskip`s I use a trick by [Heiko Oberdiek, as channeled by Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119738/14996): `\global\setlength` doesn't work with `calc`, but writing `\setlength{\mylength}{...}\global\mylength=\mylength` circumvents that.

[Much credit for the solution goes to `egreg`.]

Answer (score 3):

Double spacing is the worst setting one can apply to a document. I know that some stubborn secretary in the offices of universities keep asking for such typographic horrors that might have been justified in the olden days of typewritten theses, but nowadays have no reason.

End of rant.

I wouldn't reduce the interline space in headings beyond normal (single spaced), but a small reduction can be done; after all, with a double spaced document, this is just a very minor sin.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DoubleSpacing

\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\setSpacing{0.95}\Large\bfseries\memRTLraggedright}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{This is a chapter heading}

Look at the distance of this line to the following heading (as intended) 

\section{This is a section heading spanning two lines}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I entirely agree with the rant part.

Comment: Interesting; `\setSpacing` isn't documented in the `memoir` manual.

Comment: I was gonna try something with `\let\oldsecheadstyle\secheadstyle  \setsecheadstyle{` *something* `\oldsecheadstyle}`, which is the same as looking up the original definition of `\secheadstyle` and then prepending something (like you did). However your solution *does* affect the spacing of the heading to the body text before; I was looking for an approach that leaves that untouched.

Comment: @LoverofStructure You can use `\preto` of `etoolbox`. For the spacing, it's obvious that modifying the leading will also need an adjustment of `\beforesecskip`.

Comment: In a `\DoubleSpacing` context, `\baselineskip` with and without `\setSpacing{1}` (no need for the `\setSpacing{0.95}` you used in your example) is `22.0pt` and `36.40997pt` _within_ a section heading. Writing `\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{14.40997pt}
\section[This is a section heading spanning two lines]{\setSpacing{1}This is a section heading spanning two lines}
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-14.40997pt}` actually reduces the spacing of the heading to the text before by a fair amount. Any ideas what may be going wrong?

Comment: @LoverofStructure You should say `\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-14.4pt}`, because the value should be negative. It's a not so well known feature of LaTeX: if that skip is negative, the paragraph after the title will not be indented; in any case LaTeX uses the absolute value of the parameter for the actual spacing. No need to reset the value after `\section`: you want it to be the same for all sections, don't you? With your `\addtolength` you *reduced* the skip to about 4pt, because the normal value is about -18pt.

Comment: Thanks! About the resetting thing, that was for local experimentation (to limit unintended side effects; I used `\setSpacing{1}` and the opt-arg form `\section[...]{...}` only locally for my experiments), but you're entirely right that ordinarily the change should be a global one.

Comment: Okay, `\preto{\secheadstyle}{\setSpacing{1}}
\addtolength{\beforesecskip}{-14.41pt}` does the trick for me. (`memoir`'s `\DoubleSpacing` does `\setSpacing{1.655}` for `12pt`; we have 22pt*(1.655-1)=14.41pt, where `\baselineskip`=22pt within the `\section` heading for normal single spacing.)

Comment: The solution is essentially yours, and when I attempt to compute this value automatically (by reading off `\baselineskip` within a temporary `\secheadstyle`), the value gets lost outside the group. If you prefer to not incorporate it into your solution, I'll write a solution eventually, but it would happen much later. Let me know in that case.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I don't really see why one should try setting `\beforesecskip` “automatically”; decide the best setting for you with some tries and use `\setlength`.

Comment: The "automatic" part is for keeping the distance of the section heading to the preceding text independent of one's adjustment to the section-heading-internal spacing. Either way, I've written a solution.